# Lookup function to compare more then one column?

Tags: ssrs-expression

My lookup function doesn't work in below scenario:

```
Dataset1
Box No
Ln No

Dataset2
Box No
LN no
CT date
```

I compare both on box no and Loan no from two datasets.

If one of match is found, then it should pull the ct date.

On the below scenario, if both columns have a value in one dataset, and the second dataset has only the ln no, then it is not displaying the ct date.

```
box no      ln no       ct date
        115     115
201214      115     
201214      115     
        115     115
```

I am using the below lookup function:

```
=IIF(Lookup(Fields!Ln_no.Value & Fields!box_no.Value, Fields!Ln_no.Value & Fields!box_no.Value, Fields!ct_date.Value, "datset2"))
```

Comment: Do you need the lookup for both together (ln- and box numder, just data where both values are the same) or do you need the lookup separate? And I am not sure what exactly you want to display after the lookup?

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Ln_no.Value & Fields!box_no.Value, Fields!Ln_no.Value & Fields!box_no.Value, Fields!ct_date.Value, "datset2")
```